# VoIP/Video support on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, sip, voip

Are there any opensource or paid libraries for VoIP/Video calling in BB10 or prior?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) which is an Open Source Embedded SIP protocol stack written in C.
PJSIP library has been ported to BlackBerry10 and there are executable scripts in the [BlackBerry github repo](https://github.com/bobcripps/Cascades-Community-Samples/tree/master/bb10-pjsipdemo)

Here is a blog post for more info:
[PJSIP - BlackBerry10](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/01/port-your-pjsip-engine-to-blackberry-10-in-less-than-10-minutes/)

A success story with Truphone:
[VoIP Development on BlackBerry10](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/07/voip-development-on-blackberry-10/)

Comment: Hi William, thanks for your response. Is PJSIP licensed under GNU GPL?

Comment: Yes I believe PJSIP is using GNU GPL license:  http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/FAQ#non-gnu

Comment: Thanks! PJSIP is also available for commercial use, it's possible to arrange another licensing of that library.